How do I print generated image frames to an SDL window?
I have a method in my program that is generating frames from a "ray tracer" I am building for a class project and have been trying to have the frames print into an SDL window that opens.
My current setup has the frame generator create ppm formatted images which are stored in a vector array. After the frame has been generated it vector array is then supposed to print to the pixel values to the window but I don't know how to proceed with this. Also while trying to fix this I found I was also experiencing memory leaks which I was able to follow back to my frame generator method and am working on patching them.
Below I pasted samples of the code that I believe has my main problem of not displaying images:
// Frame generator
std::vector<color> generate_frames(const hittable &world) const
   {
      std::vector<color> frames(frame_width * frame_height);

      for (int j = frame_height - 1; j >= 0; --j)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < frame_width; ++i)
         {
            color pixel_color(0, 0, 0);
            for (int s = 0; s < samples; ++s)
            {
               ray ray = get_ray(i, j);
               pixel_color += ray_color(ray, max_depth, world);
            }
            pixel_color /= samples;
            frames[j * frame_width + i] = pixel_color;
         }
      }
      return frames;
   }

// Renderer
void render_game(Camera camera, const hittable &world)
{
   std::clog << "Render begin" << std::endl;

   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 200, 255, 255);
   std::clog << "Render color set" << std::endl; //! Debug message
   // SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
   // std::clog << "Renderer cleared" << std::endl; //! Debug message

   std::vector<color> frames = camera.generate_frames(world); // Generate the frames
   std::clog << "Frames generated" << std::endl;              //! Debug message
   void *pixels;                                              // Pixels
   std::clog << "Pixels created" << std::endl;                //! Debug message
   int pitch;                                                 // Pitch
   std::clog << "Pitch created" << std::endl;                 //! Debug message
   if (SDL_LockTexture(texture, NULL, &pixels, &pitch) != 0)  // Lock the texture
   {
      std::cerr << "SDL_LockTexture Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      std::clog << "Texture locked" << std::endl; //! Debug message
   }

   uint32_t *distance = (uint32_t *)pixels;
   std::clog << "Distance created" << std::endl;
   for (int j = 0; j < window_height; j++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < window_width; i++)
      {
         color c = frames[j * window_width + i];
         uint8_t r = static_cast<uint8_t>(255.999 * clamp(c.x(), 0.0f, 0.999f));
         uint8_t g = static_cast<uint8_t>(255.999 * clamp(c.y(), 0.0f, 0.999f));
         uint8_t b = static_cast<uint8_t>(255.999 * clamp(c.z(), 0.0f, 0.999f));
         distance[j * window_width + i] = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
      }
   }
   std::clog << "Distance set" << std::endl; //! Debug message

   SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);                     // Unlock the texture
   std::clog << "Texture unlocked" << std::endl;   //! Debug message
   SDL_RenderClear(renderer);                      // Clear the renderer
   std::clog << "Renderer cleared" << std::endl;   //! Debug message
   SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);  // Copy the texture
   std::clog << "Texture copied" << std::endl;     //! Debug message
   SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);                    // Present the renderer
   std::clog << "Renderer presented" << std::endl; //! Debug message

   frames.clear();                             // Clear the frames
   std::clog << "Frames cleared" << std::endl; //! Debug message
   std::clog << "Render end" << std::endl;     //! Debug message
   std::clog << "Game rendered" << std::endl;  //! Debug message
}


SDL texture have sizes that are not what you ordered, they get scaled up to the nearest order of 2 for example, because GPUs like that, indexing a pixel is a bit rough, a 32 bit texture that is accessed as a 32 bit number needs [i + stride / 4 * j] to access the  i'th and j'th pixel

the linked duplicate is not exactly 100% equivalent to this, as it is targeting surfaces, while you are targeting textures, but it is the same mathematics, i just couldn't find one that says Texture

you shouldn't speak of "printing". that's not printing.
